# Do Protestant catechisms teach that man is created by and for God, and God always draws man to himself?

Tags: biblical-basis, protestantism, nature-of-man, catholic-catechism

I'm looking for a comparable Protestant teaching, and hopefully the scriptural reference it's based on, for this point within the Catholic catechism.

> The desire for God is written in the human heart, because man is created by God and for God; and God never ceases to draw man to himself.
>   [CCC, n. 1](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p1s1c1.htm)

Comment: Do you want a Protestant equivalent in the sense that it agrees or simply that it touches on the same topic? Reformed/Calvinistic Protestantism would likely disagree with the overall sentiment, but an Arminian group like Methodism may, in that they disagree on the natural condition of man's heart.

Comment: I'm looking for one that agrees in the sense that there is a natural or innate desire for God, or even deity.

Comment: Which denomination of Protestant are you looking for?

Comment: I know it may be broad but that's kind of the point.  I'm trying to find similar teaching that agrees with the Catholic teaching here.

Comment: I am a little puzzled by the Catholicism tag, though. Isn't this question about Protestants?

Comment: For a discussion of a Calvinist perspective, see http://conversationsincalvinism.blogspot.com/2006/06/calvinism-and-john-1232.html which talks about John 6:44 and John 12:32. The first says: "No one can come to Me unless the Father who sent me draws him; and I will raise him up on the last day." The second says, "And I, if I am lifted up from the earth, will draw all men to Myself." The debate is over whether "all" means all people or all types of people. The Calvinist would say that only the elect are irresistibly drawn.

Comment: The intention was not to delve into predestination, soteriology, or even Catholicism.  I believe there is a natural or even existential desire to believe or be drawn toward God because He is our original source.  Even those who chase after other deities and cosmology.  This Catholic Catechism was as close as I could find to something that may agree to this view.  I am curious of other doctrinal viewpoints other than Catholicism that speaks to this view as well.  Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

From a Lutheran perspective, we believe that people will have a "god," because we are naturally driven to look for something/someone for all good things (this is essentially Luther's definition of what a god is).  So, we would agree with the statement in the Catholic Catechism that "man is a religious being."  We also would cite St. Paul in Romans 1:19-20, Acts 14:15-17, Acts 17:22ff.

However, to know the true God, we need His revelation to us which comes through the proclamation of the Gospel of Jesus Christ, as well as through the Sacraments (Baptism and the Lord's Supper).  It is through these means of grace that God calls us to Himself and justifies us sinners before Him on account of Christ.  We are naturally turned away from the true God and need Him to bring us to Himself through these means.

The Small and Large Catechisms of the Lutheran Church talk about these in more detail, particularly in the Large Catechism's exposition on the [First Commandment](http://bookofconcord.org/lc-3-tencommandments.php) and in the exposition on the [Third Article of the Apostles' Creed](http://bookofconcord.org/lc-4-creed.php).

I'll quote from the statement about the Third Article, because the catechism makes the point that it is the Holy Spirit who brings us to faith in Christ for our salvation:

> Just as the Son obtains dominion, whereby He wins us, through His
>   birth, death, resurrection, etc., so also the Holy Ghost effects our
>   sanctification by the following parts, namely, by the communion of
>   saints or the Christian Church, the forgiveness of sins, the
>   resurrection of the body, and the life everlasting; that is, He first
>   leads us into His holy congregation, and places us in the bosom of the
>   Church, whereby He preaches to us and brings us to Christ.
>
> For neither you nor I could ever know anything of Christ, or believe
>   on Him, and obtain Him for our Lord, unless it were offered to us and
>   granted to our hearts by the Holy Ghost through the preaching of the
>   Gospel. The work is done and accomplished; for Christ has acquired and
>   gained the treasure for us by His suffering, death, resurrection, etc.
>   But if the work remained concealed so that no one knew of it, then it
>   would be in vain and lost. That this treasure, therefore, might not
>   lie buried, but be appropriated and enjoyed, God has caused the Word
>   to go forth and be proclaimed, in which He gives the Holy Ghost to
>   bring this treasure home and appropriate it to us.

Answer (score 0):

The [Heidelberg Catechism](https://www.crcna.org/welcome/beliefs/confessions/heidelberg-catechism) teaches that man in his natural state hates God, which is contrary to the idea that we are naturally drawn towards God in any way.

> Q & A 4
>
> Q. What does God's law require of us?
>
> A. Christ teaches us this in
> summary in Matthew 22:37-40: "'You shall love the Lord your God with
> all your heart, and with all your soul, and with all your mind.' This
> is the greatest and first commandment. "And a second is like it: 'You
> shall love your neighbor as yourself.' "On these two commandments
> hang all the law and the prophets."
> 1 Deut. 6:5 2 Lev. 19:18
>
> Q & A 5
>
> Q. Can you live up to all this perfectly?
>
> A. No. **I have a natural
> tendency to hate God** and my neighbor.
> 1 Rom. 3:9-20, 23; 1 John 1:8,
> 10 2 Gen. 6:5; Jer. 17:9; Rom. 7:23-24; 8:7; Eph. 2:1-3; Titus 3:3

The [Westminster Larger Catechism](http://www.reformed.org/documents/wlc_w_proofs/) also teaches directly contrary to the idea that man in his natural state is in any way attracted to the true God.

> Q. 23. Into what estate did the fall bring mankind?
>
> A. The fall brought mankind into an estate of sin and misery.
>
> Q. 24. What is sin?
>
> A. Sin is any want of conformity unto, or transgression of, any law of
> God, given as a rule to the reasonable creature.
>
> Q. 25. Wherein consisteth the sinfulness of that estate whereinto man
> fell?
>
> A. The sinfulness of that estate whereinto man fell, consisteth in the
> guilt of Adam's first sin, the want of that righteousness wherein
> he was created, and the corruption of his nature, **whereby he is
> utterly indisposed, disabled, and made opposite unto all that is
> spiritually good, and wholly inclined to all evil, and that
> continually;** which is commonly called original sin, and from which
> do proceed all actual transgressions.

The [Baptist Confession of Faith of 1689](http://www.reformed.org/documents/baptist_1689.html) also teaches directly against this.

> Paragraph 4. From this original corruption, whereby we are utterly
> indisposed, disabled, and made opposite to all good, and wholly
> inclined to all evil, do proceed all actual transgressions.
>
> Rom. 8:7; Col. 1:21 12 James 1:14,15; Matt. 15:19

Comment: So, since I wasn't asking for opposing views, your answer to the question then is 'no, there is no other major teaching that agrees with the Catholic catechism'?

Comment: @Tonyg, yes, that would be correct.